# How to translate the centroid of the object in threejs while panning

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to move the centroid of the object's bounding box along with panning.
But when i pan the object the center point for rotation after panning remains the same as the previous one.Can someone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you used controls, you can use `controls.target={x,y,z}`.
And you not use it, you can use `camera.lookAt(x,y,z)`
when you used `controls`, `camera.lookAt()` can't affect anything.

Comment: I have tried this,sorry but this does not change the center for rotation.